# Running isolated Internet Explorer instances side by side? (separate cookie sets)

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, automation, cookies

I'm using PAMIE (http://pamie.sourceforge.net/) to automate some testing routines on a client's web site via IE8, and would like to be able to run multiple tests under different user credentials.

The site which I'm testing is using cookies to remember the user (without a "remember me" option I can deselect). Therefore, when I run a second instance of IE8 the cookies get shared and I can't log in as a different user.

Is there any way to get IE8 to use isolated sets of cookies in each window?

Answer (score 7):

yes, by starting internet explorer with **-nomerge** argument.

> **iexplore.exe -nomerge**

this will start a new instance of *Internet Explorer* on a new session.

Comment: this does not work, from a bit of googling it seems that it used to work in older (IE6-ish?) versions

Comment: also, PAMIE launches the browser itself in order to control it, which means I can't pass such an argument in the command line...

Comment: it works under IE8. it's all what i can confirm.

Comment: You're right, Revolter - it absolutely works.  I had to do obnoxious amounts of testing around it when we upgraded everyone in my office to insure no cross-sessions would occur (and they haven't).  

GJ - does using File -> New Session for a new window not work?

Answer (score 0):

[sandBoxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) might be able to do what you are looking to do. I don't have the full version so I can't run multiple sandboxes to test it out myself.

Comment: Actually no, you beat me. :)